# Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults. Calling Stored Procedure using JPA Repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use this page to guide myself on how to do it
https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa

I need to call a stored procedure in an Oracle DB, using Hibernate and Repositories. My procedure receives 1 IN parameter and 2 OUT parameters, I don't really use the OUT parameters in my application.

My procedure receives this

```
create or replace procedure PRD_DIC_SISTEMA(P_NRO_EVALUACION number
                                           ,P_DICTAMEN  out varchar2
                                           ,P_RESPUESTA out varchar2) is
```

My service

```
public ResultsDTO getSystemEvaluation(Long evaluationCode) throws BusinessException {
    ResultsDTO response = new ResultsDTO();
    dictaminationOperationRepository.systemDictaminationResults(evaluationCode);

    return response;
}
```

Repository

```
    public interface DictaminationOperationRepository  extends CrudRepository<DictaminationOperation,DictaminationOperationPK>{

    @Transactional
    @Procedure(procedureName="prd_dic_sistema")
    void systemDictaminationResults(@Param("p_nro_evaluacion") Long evaluationCode);        
}
```

My bean class

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name="WP_EVA_DIC_OPERACIONES")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
           @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
              name = "prd_dic_sistema", 
              procedureName = "prd_dic_sistema",
              parameters = {
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_nro_evaluacion", type = Long.class),
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "p_dictamen", type = String.class),
                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "p_respuesta", type = String.class)
              }
           )
        }
    )
public class DictaminationOperation implements Serializable {

attributes, constructor, getters and setters...

}
```

My error

> Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [prd_dic_sistema];
>   wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'PRD_DIC_SISTEMA'